# Opening a tiny browser window with no chrome

Tags: javascript, user-interface

I'd like to have a little sticky-note sized code editor that I can use to execute small bits of code and display the results.  Something that I could bring up and dismiss with a hotkey.  I'd use this thing like a glorified calculator.

I was thinking the easiest way to get something like this would be to embed the Ace editor into a tiny browser window.  This browser window would preferably have no chrome (no title bar, no status bar, no nothing) and only be 200x200 pixels or so.  And I would want to bring it up over other active windows with a hotkey.  I'm running OSX.

Can anyone advise on the best approach here?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a apendchild

HTML

```
<a href="JavaScript: windowDialog(200,200);">Window</a>
```

JavaScript

```
function windowDialog(w,h){

          var div = document.createElement('div');
          div.style.position="absolute";
         div.style.backgroundColor="red";
        div.style.width=w+'px';
        div.style.height=h+'px';
         document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```